# what is wrong this static_cast piece of code?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I have this piece of code in c++

```
char a;
cin>>a; //I input 3 in this
a=static_cast<int>(a);
cout<<a+9<<endl;
a=static_cast<int>(4.2)
cout<<a;
```

Here is the result:
51
60
4

I was expecting static_cast(a) to produce 3. Can anyone tell me what I had misunderstood?

Comment: We cannot know what you did wrong because you forgot to say what you **intended** to do. Why do you think that the result is weird? Also, don't post images of textual output. Copy the output into the question.

Comment: You entered 3 in `char` variable, then cast it to `int` -> place 51 (ascii code of '3') in `a`. So, 60 in the first output is not weird. Then you do `static_cast` to `int` of number `4.2`. Everything after float point is discarded, therefore you get an output of the symbol with ascii code 4.

Comment: What were you expecting to be printed? ASCII code 4 is a control character `EOT`, but on your terminal it's rendered as that bottom-right-corner thing that looks a bit like a J. What about this do you consider weird?

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing wrong with the code, there is something wrong with your expectation. a char is an 8 bit Number. an in is a 32 Bit number. casting a char to an int will not change something, you just have more bits set to 0. And you assigning that back to char, so the additional bits are cut again. Tell us what do you expect to get? the we are able to tell you how to do

Comment: I was taught that static conversion can be used to convert one type to another

Comment: You can't convert from text representation to integral representation using a cast.  You will need a function for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go step by step.

```
char a;
```

Declares a *character type*.  So far so good.

```
cin>>a;
```

Inputs a character, or a textual representation of a number.  If you enter '3' you will be entering the text version of 3.  On ASCII systems, this will be 0x33 (or 51 decimal).

```
a=static_cast<int>(a);
```

By the way, the value in `a` before this statement is a number (the ASCII number of the character you entered).

You are telling the compiler to convert from the integral type `char` to an integral type `int`.  *(You are converting from a smaller capacity integer type to a larger capacity integer type).* Next, you assign the `int` *type* into a `char` type. *(You are converting from a larger capacity type, `int`, to a smaller capacity type, `char`.)*  Since they are both numeric, essentially nothing happens.  The compiler may optimize this away.

```
cout<<a+9<<endl;
```

You take the character in `a` and advance the encoding by 9.  If you entered a character of 'A', you would now have 'J' (according to ASCII).  Then you output the character and a newline.

```
a=static_cast<int>(4.2)
```

Here, you are converting an *floating point* to an *integer*.  The floating point gets truncated to 4.  Next, the value 4 (0x04) gets truncated in length to fit into a `char` type and assigned to the variable `a`.

```
cout<<a;
```

This line outputs the character `\x04`.  In ASCII, this is a non-printable character, `EOT`.

What you may want is conversion from string to integer or integer to string.

Remember that 4 != '4' on most text encoding systems.